# How do you read values from a text file in c++?

Tags: c++, file

Basically I have to take 2 values (the students score and the total amount of points) from a text file that reads

```
    97 127
```

and print out the students percentage.

This is my code

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cmath>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
      int student_score;
      int total_points;
      int final_score;

      ifstream inFile;
      inFile.open("myData.txt");

      inFile >> student_score >> total_points;

      final_score = (student_score / total_points) * 100;

      cout << final_score;

      inFile.close();
      return 0;
    }
```

My problem is that when I run the program the value comes out to be

```
    3608900
```

And when I just ask to print out the student_score value it prints out a completely different number.

Comment: Always check to see  if the file actually opened before you start reading from it.

Comment: There are a plethora of similar questions and answers.  Search the internet for "stackoverflow c++ read file integer".

Comment: In addition: `student_score / total_points` returns `0` in your case, due to integer division.

Comment: It seems like file didn't be opened. Did you put it in the same directory as executable file?

Comment: I dont know what that means. Im just in a programming 1 class and need somethings explained. How do I make sure that the file is opened?

Comment: Look up the documentation for `ifstream`.  It will tell you.  [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) is a very nice reference site

Comment: use `inFile.is_open()` to check if the file is opened

Comment: Are the values in file separated by white spaces or not?

Answer (score 0):

**your bug**
`int total_points;`

You simply divide `int` / `int` and in fact you try to do this: `97 / 127` so the output is `0`.

here:

**What you should write**

```
  int student_score  = 0;
  float total_points = 0.0;
  int final_score    = 0;

  std::ifstream inFile;
  inFile.open("myData.txt");

  if( inFile ){
    inFile >> student_score >> total_points;
  } else {
      std::cout << "your-error-code";
  }

  final_score = (student_score / total_points) * 100;

  std::cout << final_score;

  inFile.close();
  return 0;
```

**output**

`76`

---

**NOTE**

Always initialize you variable to the correct related type